# How can I create a usercontrol with a panel that slides down over it's parent control?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, wpf-animation

I want to create a UserControl that displays a dropdown selection control and a couple of buttons when collapsed, but could be expanded to display a larger selection of items when desired. It's expansion panel should slide down over the controls of the Window or UserControl it's embedded in.

I can do it if all of the XAML is in the same control, but I can't figure out how to do it if I want the small view and sliding bits in a separate, re-usable, UserControl.

For a small panel I am using an animation that changes the margin of an offscreen panel and bounds clipping to make it happen. I have been copying the XAML from Window to Window. I want to make a re-usable much larger version of this, but displaying it, properly, has me a bit lost because of the bounds clipping. The UserControl clips the panel within it's smaller view, rather than allowing the panel to display over it's parent.

This is the effect I am looking for:

[image]

The primary issue seems to be that the sliding panel has to be contained within the UserControl, or it gets cut off. So the user control has to be much larger than its collapsed view. Because of that, when you want to embed it in another Window (or UserControl) you have to do XAML gymnastics to accommodate for the size of the control while making appear that the control isn't really that big.

Maybe that's just typical for XAML. I am still learning. But I can't figure out how to have a visual element of a control appear outside its bounds. A Popup doesn't really work because of how it opens and closes with focus.

At this point it's just an exercise, as I've decided to implement it a different way (modal dialog) so I have the control I need over the visuals.

Comment: To whomever downvoted, please explain why... I have researched, as I was able to implement within a single control. I can't get the effect with an embedded UserControl. What is not clear? Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried to `Style` an `Expander` and apply it when necessary?

Comment: @LittleBit, how would you style it to overcome the display issues? I added some more context, to the post, after a little more testing.